# Split a String based on a Div element

Tags: php, html, string

I have a string variable in PHP which is like

```
<html>
 <body>
   <div style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;">
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to split that String into two pieces

String 1

```
<html>
 <body>
   <div style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;">
```

String 2

```
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And then will insert some content into that DIV.

Note: Above string is just a sample to explain what I want, I have an HTML markup of 1000+ lines

As someone asked "What is your effort in PHP towards the query??"

```
$pieces = split('<div style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;">', $template);
```

But it contains the whole markup not the splited one

Comment: You can try using string interpolation: 

`"<html>
 <body>
   <div style='height: 10px; line-height: 10px;'>
     {$yourPHPContent}
   </div>
 </body>
</html>"`

Comment: No I cant ... The string is actually coming from a third-party website ... it is actually a Email template ... I want to split that and want to enter Order Detail Markup in side that DIV ... (I have ecommerce website)

Comment: It's always better to explain **what** you want to do too, not only **how**. So considering what you want to do, you'd better use a HTML DOM parser, rather than struggling with all the possible cases

Answer (score 0):

Well you could have your variable like

```
<html>
 <body>
   <div style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;">
   xyz123
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And then use `php` [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function like

```
$result = explode( 'xyz123', $yourvar );
```

then access the two parts like

```
$result[0] and $result[1]
```

Note: xyz123 is used as a unique string for demo purpose.

Comment: I tried it by passing it 

<div style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;">

But it returned inproper results

Comment: You mean passing the div element to explode function? What result you got?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need insert your content into a div? Try it:

```
$new = str_replace('<div style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;">', '<div style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;">' . $yourContent, $template);
```